# Changing localization of Ext datepicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, localization

I have a normal date field provided by ext

```
        var dateConfig = Ext.apply({}, {
            id: 'my-date'
           ,format: 'd/m/y'    
        }
        , this.dateConfig);
        var df = new Ext.form.DateField(dateConfig);
```

which is ok, and shows gregorian. Is there a way to change the date picker to show Hirji calendar?

I saw this forum post:

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?89113-Localization-of-DatePicker-short-month-names

which overrides month and day names, but that solves the problem only partially.

Also, is there a way to use jquery's calendar in ext date picker?

http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html